# Text inside buttons isn't tappable

Tags: html, css, touch

My buttons structure is as stranded as it can be:

```
<a class="button">click me</a>
```

They work just fine on click.

But, on touch devices, you can get them to work by tapping at the areas around the text inside the button. When you tab in the center "click me" it just does not work.

It is baffling me and I have not been able to find out why.

You can try it live by going to https://plutio.com from your touch device and try to tab on the Get Started button.

It won't work unless you tab around the button text.

**Things I tried:**

line height 
user-select 
box-sizing 
appearance 
pointer-events to none

Comment: which button you are talking about?
i tried 3 or 4 and found everything fine.

Comment: All of them, try and carefully tap on the text withing the button, from a touch device. I.e phone or tablet.

Comment: sorry but i couldnt find this issue. all of them are working. i tried all on header part.

Comment: yep, seems to work just fine

Comment: Did you try it on your phone or computer?

Comment: i have tried on my android device, Microsoft tab and laptop.

Comment: that's weird. Can it be happening to only me? When I tab at the center of the button it does not do anything unless I click around the text.

Comment: Can you post css?

Comment: https://plutio.com/assets/css/core.css - search for .button, button {

Comment: @Leo Are you finding this issue on iOS? iphone, ipad?

Comment: @Amitkumar iphone on both Safair and Chrome, not tested on others yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it please use below code:

```
.button:after, .button:before{
   display:none
}
```

Comment: Oh man... you are a saviour! Everything works like a charm now. THANK YOU!

Comment: That's great!, Thanks